# Can we achieve anything with the new CSS :is() pseudo-class that we can't already achieve with comma-separated queries?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've been reading up on the new *pseudo-classes* in **CSS Selectors Level 4**.

The pseudo-class `:is()` immediately caught my eye, but after an all-too-brief moment of enthusiasm... I was suddenly uncertain if it introduced any new capability at all.

In [A Guide To Newly Supported, Modern CSS Pseudo-Class Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/04/guide-supported-modern-css-pseudo-class-selectors/), Stephanie Eckles introduces several use cases, including:

- `:is(-ua-invalid, article, p)`
- `:is(#id, p)`
- `:is(p, a)`
- `:is(h1, h2, h3)`
- `:is(h2, h3):not(:first-child)`
- `p:is(article > *)`

Looks great, but... aren't these just *aliases* for:

- `-ua-invalid, article, p`
- `#id, p`
- `p, a`
- `h1, h2, h3`
- `h2:not(:first-child), h3:not(:first-child)`
- `article > p`

Apart from the fifth bullet above, the comma-separated lists of selectors are actually *shorter* (and, possibly, *more efficient*) than the `:is()` pseudo-class syntax... mostly because the `:is()` function is simply employed to enclose that list (which already represents valid syntax) in parens.

Have I missed something? Are there cleverer things you can do with `:is()` that leave comma-separated lists of CSS selectors behind?

Comment: No, they aren't. Please consider the _specificity_ of the selectors.

Comment: The specificity rule was actually a relatively recent decision after much deliberation between 1) use the specificity of the most specific argument that *matches* the element, and 2) use the specificity of the most specific argument, period. As a result the specificity of :is(#id, p) is always equal to #id, even when an element matches only the type selector.

Comment: @BoltClock - I see. I spy an opportunity for _hacks_!

Comment: @Rounin: You got it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually dealing with basic examples but consider more complex ones like the following:

```
.box h1, .box h2, .box h3, .box h4
```

In order to avoid repeating the `.box` we use

```
.box :is(h1, h2, h3, h4)
```

As far as I know, this was the main motivation for `:is()`: avoid rule duplication.

Another common example is the table selectors:

```
table tr td, table tr th
```

now will become

```
table tr :is(td, th)
```

Comment: Yep. Okay. So it's pretty much a "shorthand" for comma-separated lists of compound selectors. I suppose that's not negligible if it means that stylesheets with large amounts of (otherwise unavoidable) repetition may be considerably.slimmed down.

Comment: @Rounin yes and if you have time to search the W3C dicussion you will find that they introduced such selector specifically for this (and probably other things I missed)